# UICollectionView: animating an in-cell animation

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on card-style UI. Within a `UICollectionView` a single cell takes up most of the CollectionView frame. The CollectionView has 1 item in it. When the user wants to go to the next card (on-screen button) I use `collectionView.insertItems` to add the next 'card' and `collectionView.deleteItems` to remove the previous one. I override the layout attributes to create the effect that the old card is scaling back and the new card is animating in, on top of it:

```
override open func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let layoutAttibutes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: itemIndexPath)?.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

    layoutAttibutes.center = CGPoint(x: (layoutAttibutes.center.x), y: (layoutAttibutes.center.y) )
    layoutAttibutes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
    layoutAttibutes.zIndex = 0

    return layoutAttibutes
}

override open func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let layoutAttibutes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: itemIndexPath)?.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

    layoutAttibutes.center = CGPoint(x: (layoutAttibutes.center.x), y: (layoutAttibutes.center.y) )
    layoutAttibutes.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)
    layoutAttibutes.zIndex = 5

    return layoutAttibutes
}
```

In addition to scaling the stacking/leaving card, I want to darken it. I have a `.darkenCard()` function within my `CardCollectionViewCell` class. I trigger this from an on-screen button:

```
@IBAction func nextCard(_ sender: Any) {
    currentStepNumber += 1

    if currentStepNumber == 10 {
        currentStepNumber = 1 }

    let indexPath0 = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    let indexPath1 = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    let stackingCard = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath0) as! CardCollectionViewCell

    stackingCard.darkenCard()
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath0])

    stepList.addStepData(stepNumber: currentStepNumber)
    collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath0])

    if stepList.itemCount() != 0 {
        stepList.deleteStep(itemNumber: 0)
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath1])
    }
}
```

**Issues/Questions**

(1) The `darkenCard()` happens instantly. How do I animate to happen while the cell/card is being scaled down?

(2) When I added `.reloadItems(at:)` I get the following message each time the button is pressed:

> 2017-04-14 14:52:05.699 CardExp[98924:3166090] Snapshotting a view
>   that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your
>   view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot
>   after screen updates.

I can't quite figure what I've done (or not done) and out how to fix it.

(3) In the `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem` and `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem` how do you control the animation settings? For example, how do I add a spring or or a delay the new card animating on. What I did was to moved the initial position it further away to force it to spend some of it's animation time offscreen. It works, but it doesn't seem like the correct way to do. What should I have done?